# Fatal X server error: Failed to submit to batchbuffer

Tags: 10.04, intel-graphics, x11

Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx used to run fine on my computer. Since a few weeks, my X server crashes out of the blue while the computer is idle and I'm logged into a Gnome session. (I'm then greeted with a new GDM login prompt). After the crash, [/var/log/gdm/:0.log.1](http://pastebin.com/QytrmsDr) has the following:

> Fatal server error:
>   Failed to submit batchbuffer: Input/output error
>
> Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
>           at http://wiki.x.org
>   for help.

~/.xsession-errors.old has symptoms of X clinets dying:

> nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar) on X server :0.0.

`dmesg` says:

> [191848.390081] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* Hangcheck timer elapsed... GPU hung
>
> [191848.390086] render error detected, EIR: 0x00000010
>
> [191848.390088]   IPEIR: 0x00000000
>
> [191848.390090]   IPEHR: 0x01800002
>
> [191848.390091]   INSTDONE: 0xffffffff
>
> [191848.390093]   INSTPS: 0x8001e020
>
> [191848.390095]   INSTDONE1: 0xbfffffff
>
> [191848.390097]   ACTHD: 0x0a47b014
>
> [191848.390099] page table error
>
> [191848.390100]   PGTBL_ER: 0x00000002
>
> [191848.390103] [drm:i915_handle_error] *ERROR* EIR stuck: 0x00000010, masking
>
> [191848.390127] [drm:i915_do_wait_request] *ERROR* i915_do_wait_request returns -5 > 
>   (awaiting 5617217 at 5617205)

Is this a known problem that can be traced back to the X server from Ubuntu repositories? How would I debug this?

**Edit:** There's a relevant [bug on LP](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/555573).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symptoms reported here can have many causes. Numerous related issues have been patched in recent kernel versions already. Make sure, your system is up-to-date.